# Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 in React.js todo app after deployment on netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, undefined

I am trying to deploy the react app on netlify. Locally, my react todo app is working fine and local storage is persisting the data as well (locally). but when I deployed the web app on netlify, after visiting the live link it's showing me this error: "Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse" as it is retrieving the undefined.
Solutions I tried: checked the typo
2: checked the object in the console which is displaying the data correctly.
3: i also kept the getTodoFromLocal function inside App() function and kept initial state of
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]); (to empty array) but this is not persisting data on page reloads

my code **App.js**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Header, Form, TodoList } from './components';


// get data from local
const getTodoFromLocal = () => {
  if(localStorage.getItem("todos") === null){
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify([]));
  } else {
      try{
        let localTodo = localStorage.getItem("todos");
        let parsedTodo = JSON.parse(localTodo)
        return parsedTodo; 
      } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
   }
 }

const App = () => {
  // states
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(getTodoFromLocal());
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("all");
  const [filteredTodo, setFilteredTodo] = useState([]);

  // run this only once when app loads
  useEffect(() => {
    getTodoFromLocal();
  }, [])

  // Run once when app loads and every time when there is any change in todos ot status
  useEffect(() => {
    filterHandler();
    saveToLocal();
  }, [todos, status])

  // functions
  const filterHandler = () =>{
    switch (status) {
      case 'completed':
       setFilteredTodo(todos.filter(todo => todo.completed === true));
       break;
      case 'incompleted':
        setFilteredTodo(todos.filter(todo => todo.completed === false));
        break;
      default:
        setFilteredTodo(todos);
        break;
    }
  }

  // save to local storage / set todos;
  const saveToLocal = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
  };
  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <Form inputText = {inputText} 
        setInputText={setInputText} 
        todos={todos}  
        setTodos={setTodos} 
        setStatus={setStatus}
        />
      <TodoList 
        todos={todos} 
        setTodos={setTodos} 
        filteredTodo={filteredTodo}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**TodoList.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem';

const TodoList = ({todos, setTodos, filteredTodo}) =>  {
  return (
    <div className='todo-container'>
        <ul className='todo-list'>
          {filteredTodo && filteredTodo.map(todo => (
            <TodoItem 
              key={todo.id} 
              todo={todo} 
              todos={todos} 
              setTodos={setTodos}
              text={todo.text}
              />
          ))}
        </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default TodoList;
```

**Form.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './form.css';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';


function Form({inputText, setInputText, todos, setTodos, setStatus}) {

  const inputHandler = (e) => {
    setInputText(e.target.value);
  }

  const submitHandler = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    // generate unique id for todo lists.
    const uniqueId = uuidv4(); 
    //add todo object on click of button
    const addItem = !inputText ? alert("enter somthing")  :  setTodos([
      ...todos, {id: uniqueId, text: inputText, completed: false }
    ]);
 
    //reset the input field after adding todo
    setInputText("");

    return addItem;
  }

  // filtered todo
  const statusTodo = (e) => {
    setStatus(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <form>
        <input  type="text" className="todo-input" onChange={inputHandler} value={inputText}/>
        <button className="todo-button" type="submit" onClick={submitHandler}>
            <i className="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
        </button>
        <div className="select">
          <select onChange={statusTodo} name="todos" className="filter-todo">
              <option value="all">All</option>
              <option value="completed">Completed</option>
              <option value="incompleted">Incompleted</option>
          </select>
          <span><i className="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></span>
        </div>
  </form>
  )
}

export default Form;
```

**TodoItem.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './todo.css';

const TodoItem = ({text, todo, todos, setTodos}) => {
  //delete an item;
  const deleteHandler = () => {
    setTodos(todos.filter(el => el.id !== todo.id))
  }

  const completeHandler = () => {
    setTodos(todos.map((item )=> {
      if(item.id === todo.id){
        return {
          ...item, completed: !todo.completed
        }
      }
      return item;
    }));
  }

  return (
    <div className='todo'>
        <li className={`todo-item ${todo.completed ? 'completed' : "" }`}>{text}</li>
        <button className='complete-btn' onClick={completeHandler}>
            <i className='fas fa-check'></i>
        </button> 
        <button className='trash-btn' onClick={deleteHandler}>
            <i className='fas fa-trash'></i>
        </button> 
    </div>
  )
}

export default TodoItem;
```

Live link: https://clinquant-parfait-ceab31.netlify.app/

Github link: https://github.com/Mehreen57/Todo-app-react

Comment: The token is `undefined` in localhost so when you parse , it returns the error.

Comment: When i checked in local host it is working fine and its showing empty array initialy and its savig the todo in local storage. But after deployment on netlify its showing me undefined.

Comment: I don't know why it's storing undefined on netlify. A workaround can be that you can check if todos are not undefined. `let parsedTodo = localTodo ? JSON.parse(localTodo) : []`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the error. Going step by step.

1. You have `getTodoFromLocal` which is called when you setTodos `const [todos, setTodos] = useState(getTodoFromLocal());` here.
2. As `localStorage.getItem("todos")` is null, you set `todos` to `[]` but do not return anything which returns undefined and value of todos is **changed** to `undefined`.
3. Then you have the function `saveToLocal` in which you store `todos` in `localStorage`.which is called in useEffect whenever todos change.
4. Todos changed to `undefined` > useEffect is called > in `saveToLocal` function todos(undefined) is stored in localStorage.

updated code:

```js
if (localStorage.getItem("todos") === null) {
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify([]));
    return []
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such an explanation. I understood. I updated the code with your merge request and it's working fine now. Thank you so much for sparing your time to explain the issue step by step with the solution. It's working fine now...

P.S: I want to upvote your answer, but due to less than 15 reputation I cannot vote for your answer. so please consider my upvote with this comment.